# Understanding omission failure in distributed systems

Tags: client-server, distributed-computing

The following text says this which I'm not able to quite agree :

client C sends a request R to server S. The time taken by a communication link to transport R over the link is D. P is the maximum time needed by S to recieve , process and reply to R. If omission failure is assumed ; then if no reply to R is received within 2(D+P) , then C will never recieve a reply to R .

Why is the time here 2(D+P). As I understand shouldn't it be 2D+P ?

Answer (score 3):

Omission failures either due to process crash either due to communication link failures are detected via timeouts.
But in an asynchronous system a timeout is an *indication* only that a process is not responding. The other process *may* have crashed or just has *slowed down* due to heavy processing load.
So usually as a timeout we pick a *maximum* period. So this could be the `2(D+P)` and not your strict `2D+P`. The maximum period allows to account for either the network became congested and therefore slower on the response return/ the slower processing in the process and the time to process the response `R` that the client takes to read the message from the incoming buffer and do the processing need to pass it up to the application level.
So I can not tell you exactly what accounts as what in that formula from your book, I can tell you though that on timeouts we are not as strict as you would expect.